# How to add field via Enhancement in SM20 (SAPMSM20)

Tags: abap, alv, sap-basis

I have a requirement to display the tcode description along with tcode field(column) in the output ALV grid of the report `SM20`.
The report already contain the tcode field (column) , so just want to add an additional column in the output to show the description of tcode along with the tcode.
`TSTCT` is the table and `TTEXT` is the field for tcode description.
How can i achieve this using enhancement .

I have searched and found that in the include `rsau_class_auditlist_impl`
there is a method i.e METHOD `write_list_about_auditlog`. In that method the itab is filled by

```
go_sal_rf->get_result_tab( EXPORTING id_reset = abap_false
                           CHANGING et_out_ext = mt_outtab_l ).
```

So as for me I have to implement the enhancement in this method. 
Please, guide me how will I do the enhancement, so that it will display one column in the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to concatenate the additional data into the table mt_outtab, you can do this via implicit enhancement in `rsau_class_auditlist_impl`.

My recommendation would be:
Add an additional Column to ts_out_ext in `CL_SAL_READ_FILES` line 145, this type definition can be enhanced, but you need to check where it's used.

Alternatively, you could replace program id with tcode description when the tcode description isn't empty, and re-purpose the programID field.
You would do this at the end of method `WRITE_LIST_ABOUT_AUDITLOG` line 167 has an ehnacement spot.